# Problem with Example II.6.6.3 in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne says in this example that the twisted cubic curve cannot be a set-theoretical complete intersection of a smooth quadric and another surface (since the twisted cubic on the quadric has type $(1, 2)$). However, the Wikipedia entry on twisted cubic says that it *is* a set-theoretical complete intersection ([see the section "Properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Twisted_cubic&oldid=803962805)). I tried to find the intersection of the two surfaces given in Wikipedia, and it seems that it is indeed the twisted cubic. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Not everyone has that book, so I suggest you to modify your question adding the exercise written in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hartshorne is correct. Twisted cubic is the set-theoretic complete intersection of a singular quadric and a cubic. It is NOT a set-theoretic complete intersection where the quadric is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in order to close it. Mohan noted in comments that the quadric on Wikipedia is singular.